# How to use for loop combine with if else in mustache js

Tags: mustache

link.href is an url in json and I want to show this to html.
First, I loop the links in jquery and find the `link.href` which it's `link.rel = 'next'`

```
  var feed = data.feed;
  var links = feed.link || [];

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
      if (link.rel == 'next'){
        link.href = true;
      }
  };

  var template = $('#test-tpl').html();
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template, feed);
  $('.folders').html(html);
```

Then i use this in my HTML but not working but the link.href not showing up.

```
{{#link.href}}
{{link.href}}
{{/link.href}}
```